# Why do most scripting languages use less memory?

Tags: java, php, python, ruby, benchmarking

I've just had a look at some programming language benchmarks here: http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/u64q/compare.php?lang=php&lang2=java

I noticed that languages like PHP, Ruby and Python were slower, but surprisingly used less memory than Java in most benchmarks. What is the reason for that?

Comment: Please feel free to leave a comment **telling me the reason for the downvote**

Comment: totally right, i'm curious too

Comment: IMO this quesiton is very good, but too broad for stackoverflow (dunno why I'm listed with those who close it as opinion-based - it is not opinion based).

Comment: We can sensibly interpret the question as being about measurements of specific programs -- that's a matter of knowledge and profiling, not a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use Oracle Java the Java programs are not compiled to native machine code which can immediately be executed by the CPU, but to an intermediate form called "java byte code".

The Java environment which executes this java byte code include a sophisticated compiler which can generate very good native machine code as it keep track of what the program actually do, and where it makes good sense to spend a lot of effort optimizing the machine code.  Unfortunately all this bookkeeping takes up memory and the compiler itself also does, along with the rest of the Java environment.  Also the garbage collection mechanisms cleaning up unneeded objects also needs additional memory to work well (i.e. fast).

All this result in Java programs needing a lot of memory even for small programs.

Comment: I see. But isn't interpreting PHP and the automatic memory management it has memory-expensive as well?

Comment: It does not have, I wanted to delete it but couldn't. Firstly I wrote that your answer was the opposite of what the question assumed, later on I saw I was wrong,,, tried to delete my comment and upvoted you ^^'

Comment: @MinecraftShamrock To my understanding the PHP interpreter does a lot less work by not compiling to native machine code and therefore executes code slower than Java does.  This requires a lot less bookkeeping and therefore not as much memory.

Comment: I think Java runtime is much larger than in Python or PHP. Java loads more stuff, even if it's not used.

Comment: Specifically, for those Java programs shown on the benchmarks game website, because the default heap size is not set on the command line, the initial and maximum heap sizes are calculated based on the amount of memory on the machine.